# Hindi keyboard automatically added

Tags: windows-10-mobile, keyboard, language-setting

When I purchased my phone it came with a Hindi keyboard built-in. As I am living in India this is ordinary. I don't type in Hindi and I removed it. However it keeps adding itself automatically despite having a regional language installed.

[image]

How to prevent the keyboard from installing automatically?

Comment: It seems national language is considered 'Default'. ;)
Have you tried making English as default?

Comment: @MaheshMankar English(India) is the always my default language. I removed completly from my phone and only the keyboard adds itself again.